# generate a table that keep showing individual rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have just started learning sql and I have a question:

Which function we should use to generate a table that keep showing individual rows but able to calculate per group?
Is it CTE, Group By, Aggregate, or Window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- CTE is not a function
- GROUP BY will group rows with additional calculations per group
- WINDOW functions compute values over a group of rows and return a single result for each row.

So the answer is WINDOW functions since GROUP BY will not retain individual records.

An example:

**GROUP BY**

```
SELECT
  letter,
  SUM(number) AS aggregate
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      'A' AS letter,
      2 AS number
    UNION ALL
(    SELECT
      'A' AS letter,
      3 AS number)
    UNION ALL
(    SELECT
      'C' AS letter,
      6 AS number)
  ) AS table_3
GROUP BY
  letter
```

Output:

| letter | aggregate |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| C | 6 |

**WINDOW**

```
SELECT
  letter,
  SUM(number) OVER (PARTITION BY letter) AS `window`
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      'A' AS letter,
      2 AS number
    UNION ALL
(    SELECT
      'A' AS letter,
      3 AS number)
    UNION ALL
(    SELECT
      'C' AS letter,
      6 AS number)
  ) AS table_3
```

Output:

| letter | window |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| C | 6 |

Source: https://count.co/sql-resources/bigquery-standard-sql/window-functions-explained